# class hierarchy design - order of classes

Tags: php

What is the best way to order a a group of classes.  I've already made the decision to put them in one file.  An opcode caching application well ensure efficiency.

Is alphabetical O.K? Does it matter?  Here is the list.

```
/*CLASS LIST*/

  /*bookmark*/
  /*database*/
  /*import*/
  /*one_db*/
  /*post*/
  /*route*/
  /*session*/
  /*signup*/
  /*table_maintain*/
  /*tweet*/
  /*upload*/
  /*validate*/
  /*view_html*/
```

Comment: is one_db some kind of database?

Comment: Why do you want to put them all in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes like "one" and "tablem" seem to be a bit confusing. When someone looks into your application, even first line of class has to tell him/her, what does it do, what is that class for.

Comment: @ChrisAaker: I just feel it fits more for an answer rather than for a comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parent classes before child classes.  So alphabetical with classes moved to take into account parent/child relationships.